# disnake[voice] / PyNaCl не устанавливается

Tags: android, termux, disnake

Столкнулся с проблемой, PyNaCl не хочет устанавливаться, нужен он мне для поддержи голосового чата в disnake. Пробовал устанавливать `python3-dev` и т.п(они были не найдены). Пробовал всё что предлагал мне хром. Может проблема из-за termux'а?

```
Building wheels for collected packages: PyNaCl
  Building wheel for PyNaCl (pyproject.toml) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error

  × Building wheel for PyNaCl (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [198 lines of output]


дальше идёт спам


[end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyNaCl
Failed to build PyNaCl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyNaCl, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Оказывается ответ был очень даже прост:

```
SODIUM_INSTALL=system pip install pynacl
```